# How to search user input for specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a site where I am trying to add multiple barcodes to a database.  The bulk add works great, except I have a "special" series of barcodes that include an "F" at the end.  This signals a different stored procedure to be called for inserting the books.  However, whenever I try to run it I get a SQL ERROR.  The F at the end of the the barcode is the issue.  If i'm trying to add 1000 - 1005 it works fine.  If I do 1000F - 1005F it does not because my SQL doesn't know what to do with the F...

Comment: Are you able to show us what the barcode actually contains? Wondering if there is a special character in it

Comment: I think I figured out the issue... but have no idea how to fix it or apply it... I'm doing a bulk add... so lets say I want to add... 30F - 50F When I type in 50F in the "Ending barcode" it tries to do the math (30f-50F) Since it can't subtract letters... it comes up with a SQL Error... How do I strip the "F" out of the barcode parameter when checking that?  I'll edit my code above...

Comment: Well, the issue your getting with the actual error message has been answered below, you're missing ' around the string parts of your sproc call. If you want to remove the F then you could do one of many things, like dim txt = x_sBarCode.Text.Replace("F", ""). Seems like a different question though? unless i'm missing something?

Comment: the ' is not missing... that's documentation... ''Encrypted Coupon Books is documentation not a sp call...

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code in opened for sql injection, you should correct this asap.
You can read about sql injection here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

And now about your problem. I am almost certain you are missing ' chars when you set mySQL.
Use SqlCommand to pass parameters in safe way. Passing parameters is also described in provided link.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you have wrapped your bar-code in apostrophes

try this: the first mySQL has the text wrapped in `'`

this is assuming usp_Insert_Encrypted is taking in strings

```
Dim mySQL as String
    if InStr(x_sBarcode.Text, "F") > 1 then 'Encrypted Coupon Books           
       mySQL= "EXEC usp_Insert_Encrypted '" & x_sBarCode.Text & "','"  & x_sBarCodeSeriesEnd.Text & "'," & v_lBookTypeId
      ''---------------------------------^-----------------------^--^--------------------------------^
    Response.Write(mySQL)
    else
       mySQL = "EXEC sp_BulkInsert 1," & x_sBarCode.Text & "," & x_sBarCode.Text & "," & x_sBarCodeSeriesEnd.Text
    end if
```

**UPDATE**:

Added some ----^ pointing to what I am mean regarding `'`

you have:

```
mySQL= "EXEC usp_Insert_Encrypted " & x_sBarCode.Text & ","  & x_sBarCodeSeriesEnd.Text & "," & v_lBookTypeId
```

Where it might likely need to be: (assuming the first 2 parameters are text and the last one is an integet

```
mySQL= "EXEC usp_Insert_Encrypted '" & x_sBarCode.Text & "','"  & x_sBarCodeSeriesEnd.Text & "'," & v_lBookTypeId
      ''--------------------------^-----------------------^--^--------------------------------^
```

Comment: No, I mean in the actual mySQL line... after EXEC usp_Insert_Encrypted and before " & x_sBarcode.Text you should have a ' because you're trying to push a string into the sproc

Comment: That's not the issue.  the issue is the "F" at the end.  the bulk add does the math... so if i wand book 1 - 5 it says ok i need to add books 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5... with the F... it trys to say ok... I need to add f, f, f, f... in other words... I need it to not look at the F... but the F is part of the barcode so it needs to be there.

Comment: So you want to take the F off before adding it to the stored procedure?

Comment: The F is crucial, it's part of the barcode... however i can get it added... it needs to be in when it's sent to the SP

Comment: I'm sorry, you're not making sense to me. If you're telling me it needs to be there when you pass it into the SP parameter then you're call to the SP is wrong - as stated in my answer. If you can add the F inside the SP and want to pass the barcode withouth the F then just before you call the SP create a variable and assign it the x_sBarcode.Text and replace the F with an empty string, like var code = x_sBarcode.Text.Replace("F", "") - then add the F in the SP.

Comment: Here is what the issue is... I have 2 sets of barcodes... if I add an "F" in the text box section it knows to add the "encrypted" barcode... if I do not add the F in the textbox it knows to add a NORMAL barcode.  I also have a POS system that uses the same stored procedure so i'd like to keep it uniform, and have the complex code on the webapp backend... There has to be a way for it to discregard the F as far as "Math" goes (deciding how far to add) 1-5 means it needs to add 1f 2f 3f 4f 5f...

Comment: I can't help any further. I have showed you why you're getting an SQL Exception, Gregor also pointed you in that direction. I have also showed you how you can take the F off the barcode. Somewhere along the line there is confusion in what you're asking and what we're reading.

Comment: Indeed.  You're help is MUCH appreciated!  I'll work on it from here.